# Best practice to extend an object

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, di

What's the best practice and recommended way to extend an object like **\Magento\Store\Model\Store** with a new object property.

I want to do something like this:

```
$storeManager; //StoreManagerInterface
foreach($storeManager->getStores() as $store) {
    $language = $store->getLanguage(); // < this should be an own object from my custom module
}
```

I think I should use the **`di config`**. Does anybody has a good idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Magento recommends to use composition instead of inheritance.
If you want to use any object in your class, then you can include that in your class using [constructor dependency injection](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html) 
To inject a non-injectable class in your class, Magento recommends to use [factories](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/factories.html)
Also, Magento recommends to use [Public Interfaces](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/api-concepts.html) and [Service Contracts](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html) while creating your custom functionality.